# Select locales on ubuntu 10.04 after installation

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, localization

When I activate a new rackspace ubuntu 10.04 instance I keep getting these messages:

> perl: warning: Please check that your
>   locale settings:  LANGUAGE = (unset),
>     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
>   "de_DE.UTF-8"
>       are supported and installed on your system.

How do I select and configure the locales correctly?

**Edit:** This was given to me by Rackspace support, it also worked, maybe it helps someone with ubuntu 10.04:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check that your desired locale is available on your system:

```
locale -a
```

If your locale is not available:

- Find the line with your desired locale in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`
- Copy the whole line to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`
- Regenerate locales using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Once the locale is made available, enable it by editing `/etc/default/locale`, e.g.:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```